# Transforming values from one column to other if it has multiple values

Tags: r

IF ID has multiple START and STOP values move them to new START and STOP columns. if ID has 5 START and STOP values then ID should have all the values in one row. with 5 START and 5 STOP. ID has max of 7 values.

Current DF.

```
ID        |       START           |     STOP

LB1    2020-04-01 03:46:03   2020-04-01 04:27:30

LB1    2020-04-01 10:07:08    2020-04-01 10:40:10

LB2    2020-04-02 17:01:23    2020-04-02 17:40:50

LB3   2020-04-03 17:04:56    2020-04-03 17:38:47

LB4    2020-04-04 18:35:34     2020-04-04 19:11:05
 
LB4    2020-04-06 09:48:07     2020-04-06 10:24:10
```

expected output

```
ID        |      START              |      STOP          |     START                |      STOP               |START           |     STOP   


LB1  2020-04-01 03:46:03     2020-04-01 04:27:30    2020-04-01 10:07:08   2020-04-01 10:40:10

LB2   2020-04-02 17:01:23   2020-04-02 17:40:50

LB3   2020-04-03 17:04:56   2020-04-03 17:38:47

LB4   2020-04-04 18:35:34    2020-04-04 19:11:05  2020-04-06 09:48:07     2020-04-06 10:24:10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try `reshape` + `transform` when with base R

```
reshape(
  transform(
    df,
    q = ave(1:nrow(df), ID, FUN = seq_along)
  ),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "ID",
  timevar = "q"
)
```

which gives

```
         ID             START.1              STOP.1             START.2
1 LB1            2020-04-01 03:46:03 2020-04-01 04:27:30 2020-04-01 10:07:08
3 LB2            2020-04-02 17:01:23 2020-04-02 17:40:50                <NA>
4 LB3            2020-04-03 17:04:56 2020-04-03 17:38:47                <NA>
5 LB4            2020-04-04 18:35:34 2020-04-04 19:11:05 2020-04-06 09:48:07
               STOP.2
1 2020-04-01 10:40:10
3                <NA>
4                <NA>
5 2020-04-06 10:24:10
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("LB1", "LB1", "LB2", 
"LB3", "LB4", "LB4"), START = c("2020-04-01 03:46:03",
"2020-04-01 10:07:08", "2020-04-02 17:01:23", "2020-04-03 17:04:56", 
"2020-04-04 18:35:34", "2020-04-06 09:48:07"), STOP = c("2020-04-01 04:27:30",
"2020-04-01 10:40:10", "2020-04-02 17:40:50", "2020-04-03 17:38:47",
"2020-04-04 19:11:05", "2020-04-06 10:24:10")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options using  @ThomasIsCoding's data.

With `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = row, values_from = c(START, STOP))

# ID    START_1             START_2             STOP_1              STOP_2             
#  <chr> <chr>               <chr>               <chr>               <chr>              
#1 LB1   2020-04-01 03:46:03 2020-04-01 10:07:08 2020-04-01 04:27:30 2020-04-01 10:40:10
#2 LB2   2020-04-02 17:01:23 NA                  2020-04-02 17:40:50 NA                 
#3 LB3   2020-04-03 17:04:56 NA                  2020-04-03 17:38:47 NA                 
#4 LB4   2020-04-04 18:35:34 2020-04-06 09:48:07 2020-04-04 19:11:05 2020-04-06 10:24:10
```

with `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)

dcast(setDT(df), ID~rowid(ID), value.var = c('START', 'STOP'))
```